# Identify Movie: Angry gorillas and automated gun turrets

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a movie about 10-15 years ago about some exploration group in the jungle being attacked by very angry gorillas or apes while defending their camp with automated gun turrets at night.

I know it seems like a long shot but its all I can remember, since I was 11 or 12 years old. :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds very much like [Congo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112715/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), the 1995 adaptation of Michael Crichton's novel of the same name.

The story involves an expedition to a lost city which is defended by a breed of gorillas who were trained as guardians of the city.  The gorillas kill by smashing victims' heads between two large rocks.

The expedition used a lot of high technology gadgets, including automated motion-sensing defensive turrets (which were triggered while they were sleeping, and kept the gorillas at bay).

Comment: Ahh, brilliant guys!  
Turns out I do remember more of this movie, just didnt realise it was the same movie as the one with the monkey who could do sign language.

Comment: Is Congo even SciFi? Not all stuff by Chrighton is IIRC.

Comment: @DVK IIRC, the gorillas were mutations bred by an ancient mythical civilization... the scifi elements were light, but present, imo.

Answer (score 4):

This may be the movie [Congo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congo_%28film%29). Although I've not seen it, Wikipedia's plot summary includes the following, which seems to match your description.

> Gray gorillas then attack the perimeter after dark and are driven off by automated machine guns set up by Karen.